# How can i add data to firestore ? I just study about firebase and the tutorial different UI from me and the debug show the problem below

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

W/Firestore(27093): (24.9.1) [Firestore]: Write failed at collection/y9CfklVGhkx0H5g03qED: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

I want to insert data to the database

[image: This is my tutorial code]

[image: This is my code]

[This is the my firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjjPb.png)
[This is my tutorial firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RKDE.png)

This is my first time in stack overflow. if there any mistake please help correct me

[image: The entire code]

Comment: Hi please show your code that you are using to enter the data.

Comment: Your database is set to not allow the access from your code. See the questions I linked, and some of the many other [questions about this topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+firestore+write+failed+PERMISSION_DENIED).

Comment: @YashasMajmudar I just update my code

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i just change the rule as the instruction but still not work with the same error

Comment: have you added your debug key to the firebase console?

Comment: I just solve the problem by go to firebase database not realtime database. and then go to rule and from false to true .Just want to inform that this method not sure it secure or not

Comment: You're allowing everyone in the world full (read and/or write, depending on which setting you changed), so... no, that is definitely not secure. To allow secure direct access from your clients, you have to specify in your security rules exactly what is and isn't allowed.  Follow the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started) to get started with that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i see their is a 'configure app check ' if i configure . is it make my firestore security ?

Comment: Go in Database -> Rules ->

For development:

Change allow read, write: if false; to true;

Note: It's quick solution for development purpose only because it will turns off all the security. So, it's not recommended for production.
For production:

If authenticated from firebase: Change allow read, write: if false; to request.auth != null;

Comment: There's no such thing as being secure, there's only secured against attacks of a certain type. Without naming/enumerating the type of attack, there's no answer. Enabling App Check reduces the abuse you'll see from code that's not inside your app. But it doesn't eliminate it completely, nor does it protect against other attacks.